# magento get block in cms page

Tags: php, magento

i'm install banner module -
ibanner in xml file

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="ibanners/view" name="ibanners.homepage">
            <action method="setGroupCode"><group_code>home</group_code></action>
            <action method="setDisplayControls"><controls>1</controls></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>`
```

and banners shows in main page, how can i get them in cms page? i'm trying something like `{{block type="ibanners/view" template="ibanners/default.phtml" name="ibanners.homepage" }}`
but it's not working

Comment: You have double quotes " in the template attribute and also try to change the name of the block to something different for example like ibanners.aboutpage

Answer (score 0):

{{block type="ibanners/view" template="ibanners/default.phtml" name="ibanners.homepage" }}

Copy above code  it will work :)